# APM best settings

Tags: power-management

I mean this one:

[image]

What's the best setting for this? Best for performance.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly defined on the sliding bar.

[image]

As APM level increase as performance is better but consumes much power, but as you do down the performance decrease while saving more power.

So you have to choose what you want? you want power saving or you care much for performance so move the slider to your needs.

Comment: @RoldanLT you are welcome friend